# Methods for updating SHA-1 fingerprint on IOT devices

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iot, esp8266

Disclaimer: Complete newbie trying to wrap my head around SSL.

I am developing a device using an ESP8266 which needs to connect securely to a known server for IOT purposes, we will develop and control the server endpoint as well as the ESP8266 based client (BearSSL etc), we will not control the SSL certificate updates on the hosted server and need to manage the changing certificate keys.

Using the SHA-1 fingerprint for the certificate installed on the server appears to be the most straightforward approach and will provide the basic security we need. The data we will be exchanging is not sensitive or mission critical, we just need to keep the web server happy going into the future.

I understand the need to update the SHA-1 fingerprint on the client when the server certificate updates and this would typically be done with a firmware update over a secure connection. Our use case will make this very difficult for various reasons, so I am trying to establish the best method for updating the fingerprint as it changes without requiring re-flashing/OTA updates.

What I don't understand is why there is a need to protect/hide/embed the fingerprint when any public user or hacker can visit our SSL server site and obtain the fingerprint through a browser or OpenSSL query. Can I simply not retrieve the current fingerprint (maybe encode it with our own basic encryption) from a known HTTP non SSL server perhaps running PHP which will obtain and calculate the current fingerprint of our SSL server for use by our IOT device ? Our device would query the HTTP server first, retrieve the fingerprint and store it in EEPROM until it expires, then simply re-obtain the new fingerprint as required. Then it goes off and talks to the SSL server.

So the crux of the question is, if a hacker can get the fingerprint straight from our SSL server, why would this be an unsafe approach, which I'm sure it is ?

I don't want to go down the trusted root CA with long expiry approach as our devices may need to run for 20-30 years and we'll need a device certificate update procedure regardless, and would prefer not to use ClientInsecure() if possible.

Assuming the non-SSL HTTP approach is no good, can anybody suggest an alternate automated method for retrieving the current fingerprint securely ? I have to assume our devices may get left in a cupboard or disconnected from Wifi for years at a time and need to automatically re-connect in the future without a firmware update.

Many thanks, and be gentle *8)

Comment: If you don't want to by-pass the server cert verification with `ClientInsecure()`, for an esp8266, it will take about 5-10 seconds (quite long) each time when the client connect to the server to verify the server cert, you might want to consider to have a hardware secure element to offload the security to the dedicated chip. I don't have comment on other parts of your question as I read a couple of times, not quite sure what you want.

Comment: For your first question: The reason client needs to have server cert fingerprint is for SSL pinning check. This is technique to prevent from man-in-the-middle attack target to device in HTTPS channel. For your second question: You can use HTTPS to update the server ssl cert fingerprint. Note, you can keep the old server ssl cert fingerprint to make sure compatibility while server is still running with old ssl cert.

Answer (score 2):

Your question may be removed as inappropriate for Stack Overflow but it's a really interesting one and I'm hoping you'll at least get a chance to see this answer.

First of all, there is absolutely no need to hide the fingerprint of the server's certificate. As you pointed out, anyone can get the fingerprint directly from the server itself.

If you're downloading the fingerprint from a different source in order to update your embedded device then it's not privacy you need, it's authentication - that you're getting it from the source you think you're getting it from - and integrity - that the fingerprint hasn't been corrupted or modified during transmission.

Which leads you to a chicken and egg problem. If you serve the updated fingerprint through non-HTTPS servers then it's vulnerable to modification and the servers are vulnerable to impersonation. If you serve it via HTTPS then you still have the issue of verifying the HTTPS server you're getting the fingerprint from.

You could use a pre-shared key to sign and verify the downloaded fingerprint. The embedded device would use a public key to decrypt a signed fingerprint, the server would have the private key to sign it. Then you face an entire new set of issues if the private key is every compromised - key revocation and distribution, which is part of the problem you're trying to skirt here with this whole process.

You're also going to want to do better than SHA-1. SHA-1 hasn't been considered cryptographically secure for years.

And in 20 - 30 years time, it's likely that whatever algorithm you're using will also cease to be cryptographically secure. Which means that you'll need to update the fingerprint algorithm over the course of decades.

Instead of using the fingerprint, you can embed in the device's firmware the top level certificate of the Certificate Authority that signed the server's certificate, but CA certificates will also expire well before 20-30 years elapse, and may also be revoked. If you embed the CA certificate then the web server will have to supply the embedded device with its entire certificate chain so that the device can verify signatures at each step, which on an ESP8266 may be very, very slow, even today.

In fact, it's quite likely that web servers 20-30 years from now won't use the same cyphers for SSL as they do today, and it's likely they won't continue to support the version of TLS (1.3) that's standard now. So you would need to be able to update your embedded software to TLS 1.8 or 2.0 or whatever the version will be that's needed 20-30 years from now. And the ESP8266 is not particularly fast at computing today's cyphers... it may be computationally impractical for it to compute the cyphers of decades in the future.

In fact, wifi 20-30 years from now will quite possibly not support hardware from today as well as wifi protocols evolve and also require updated cypher suites.

I'm also dubious that ESP8266's are likely to run continuously for 20 years without hardware failures. The main feature of the ESP8266 is that it's cheap, and cheap does not often correspond with reliability or longevity.

With much better performance, the ESP32 (still cheap) would stand a better chance to being able to compute the cyphers in use 20-30 years from now and support the future's wifi standards, but with its (and the ESP8266's) closed source wifi implementation you'd be at the mercy of Espressif to provide updates to its wifi stack 20 years from now, which I doubt will happen.